# DevExpress Controls not visible in Visual Studio toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress

I've just installed DXperienceXaf-10.1.7, but the controls do not appear in the VS 2010 toolbox, neither do they show in the VS 2008 toolbox.  I have run ToolboxCreator from the 'start menu' shortcut to no avail.  This is on Windows 7.

Is there a fix for this?  If not, how do I manually add them?  There seem to be a zillion dll files.

Comment: `ToolboxCreator` work for me for `DevExpress 22.2` in `VS0219`. I prefer to use it from installation path `C:\Program Files\DevExpress 22.2\Components\Tools` and not from the Start Menu. The reason is, if you have multiple version installed for `DevExpress` then from Start Menu you have to make sure that you select `ToolboxCreator` belong to the path from your desired version of `DevExpress`, otherwise you may end up installing toolbox for older version and you won't get desired outcome.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can manually add them by creating a new DevExpress Toolbox Tab and dragging all the DLLs from

"C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 2010.1\Components\Sources\DevExpress.DLL"

Remove (x86) for a 32 bit Windows installation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: never knew you could drag a DLL to here. Thanks , that solves the problem for the most part.  Wish DE could get it working , but this will help me move on. Using DE ver21, VS ver20222

Answer (score 7):

Although question quite old, I often get this problem when installing a DevExpress upgrade. Steps to get it working are:

- 'Repair' the DevExpress installation
- Run the Toolbox Creator from the Start Menu

Also one thing I noticed with this version is that the toolbox only seems to appear on .Net Framwork 3.5 and above web projects.

Had this issue with Dev Express v2011 vol 2.

Hope it helps.

Comment: v21 toolbox creator doesnt seem to do mucj

Answer (score 4):

DevExpress Controls not showing up (disable) in Visual Studio toolbox:

This issue was caused by the application Target Framework being set to .Net Framework 2.0

once the Target Framework was changed to 4.0, the controls became available in the Toolbox.

To change the Target Framework in Visual Studio : 
For VB.net:

1. Right click the project in the Solution Explorer and click Properties...
2. On the Compile tab, click the Advanced Compile Options... button
3. Change the Target framework (all configurations) to .NET Framework 4.

For C# .net:

1. Right click the project in the Solution Explorer and click Properties...
2. Click the Application tab and change the Target framework to .NET Framework 4.

After that you need to repair toolbox by right clicking on toolbox tab, where controls exist. Visual Studio will close automatically and will reopen after some configuration will apply. Now you will find all devExpress Controls available on toolbox..

Thank you...

Pulkit Aggrawal 
(email: pulkit.aggarwal.333@gmail.com)

[JITR Technology]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you grab the installation's log (it should be positioned near the installer) and send it to the devexpress by creating a new ticket in the [support center](http://devexpress.com/support/center).  We will research why the problem appears using it and let you know what causes this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just repair the DevEx from the DevEx Setup

Answer (score 1):

Lest do like this: 
1. Open your visual studio
2. Open your solution, for example in mine is mngpwn (it's windows form app) 
3. Set application target .net framework to .net 4.7 or above 
4. On opened solution in visual studio solution exploler, open the form. In mine is Form1.cs [Design], 
5. actived Toolbox, select General Tab, 
6. Restore down the visual studio windows 
7. Open windows explorer an go to folder of installed DexExpress dll file 
8. Restore down the window exploler 
9. select view as Detail View and then sort view by Type file 
10. Go to window exploler, select the .dll stored. In mine is in C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 13.2\Components\Bin\Framework, 
11. Drag to general tab on toolbox, 
12. Wait a momen. When appear the dialog window, click Ok, 
13. Rename the general tab in tooolbox as you want, 
14. Make new tab and move the group of DevExpress Component you want to group, 
15. Done!
16. You now can use all of DevExpress component.
17. Do the same for web component in web solution type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic steps to display DevExpress toolbar; for beginners.
Select View > Toolbox. Select anywhere on the toolbox and right click and select Add Tab. 
You need to name this tab. Right click on this new group, select Choose Items. A dialog box appears and it might take a while to load the components. 
If DevExpress components are not present here, click on Browse and select the dll files. This will add all the items to the new group.